# uidatepicker -nsdate incremement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

is it possible to increment a NSDATE by month? For example, nsdate = 12/10/01 , adding one month making it 12/11/01.

Comment: 16 questions and 0 accepted... It's really worth reviewing your old questions and mark answers that solved your problem as accepted

Comment: on a unrelated note - if you want to increment date by 1 month - how uidatepicker is related here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use NSCalendar class for calendar calculations:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comp setMonth: 1];
NSDate* newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:oldDate options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
```